# Python: Append a list to an existing dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, percentage

I have a dictionary with an int as value for each key. I also have total stored in a variable. I want to obtain a percentage that each value represent for the variable and return the percentage to the dictionary as another value for the same key.

I tried to extract the values in a list, then do the operation and append the results to another list. But I don't know how to append that list to the dictionary.

```
total = 1000

d = {"key_1":150, "key_2":350, "key_3":500}

lst = list(d.values())

percentages = [100 * (i/total) for i in lst]


# Desired dictionary

d

{"key_1": [15%, 150],

"key_2": [35%, 350],

"key_3": [50%, 500]
}
```

Comment: You could do... ```d["key_1"].append(percentages)``` You could create a for loop that iterates through the percentages list, so you add one percentage to each ```key_1```. Let me know if that doesn't answer your question and I'll be back!

Comment: @McFloofenbork: That would put *all* the `percentages` on `key_1` only, and it wouldn't work anyway (because the original `dict` has `int` values, not `list` values).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I see youre right. Hmm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off avoiding the intermediate `list` and just updating each key as you go:

```
total = 1000

d = {"key_1":150, "key_2":350, "key_3":500}

for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = [100 * (v / total), v]
```

While it's technically possible to `zip` the `dict`'s keys with the values of the `list`, as long as the keys aren't changed and the `list` order is kept in line with the values extracted from the `dict`, the resulting code would *reek* of code smell, and it's just easier to avoid that `list` entirely anyway.

Note that this won't put a `%` sign in the representation, because there is no such thing as a percentage type. The only simple way to shove one in there would be to store it as a string, not a `float`, e.g. replacing the final line with:

```
    d[k] = [f'{100 * (v / total)}%', v]
```

to format the calculation as a string, and shove a `%` on the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
total = 1000
d = {"key_1": 150, "key_2": 350, "key_3": 500}
d1 = {k: ['{}%'.format(v * 100 / 1000),v] for k, v in d.items()}
print(d1)
```

output

```
{'key_1': ['15.0%', 150], 'key_2': ['35.0%', 350], 'key_3': ['50.0%', 500]}
```